# How are these scrollbars customized?

Tags: jquery, html, css, webkit, scrollbar

I am trying to create scrollbar like in the following website:

[image: scrollbar]

I didn't find it in the code nor in the stylesheets.

Can you tell me how is this achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's making use of the WebKit's `-webkit-scrollbar` pseudo-elements. A complete list of them is:

- `-webkit-scrollbar`
- `-webkit-scrollbar-button`
- `-webkit-scrollbar-track`
- `-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece`
- `-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`
- `-webkit-scrollbar-corner`
- `-webkit-resizer`

Also, you can find more information in the [WebKit announcement](https://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/). Also, [here is a direct link to the example](http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/overflow-scrollbar-combinations.html) listed in the announcement.

Comment: You can check info on what Alexander says here: http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/